# Is there an easy way to populate a ListView by a DataTable?

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, datatable

The `DataGridView` has a property "DataSource" that can simply be assigned to a `DataTable` to populate it. This means we don't have to worry about the names/number of columns in the `DataTable`.

But, I haven't found a similar way of populating a `ListView`. It seems that you need to know how many columns the `DataTable` has and the names of each in order to do this, making it much more difficult.

Can anyone suggest an easy way to populate a `ListView` like we can with a `DataGridView`?

Comment: Given a DataTable, you know the number of columns and their names perfectly well - its in the Columns property. Why do you think it is difficult to populate a ListView that way?

Comment: Why not just use the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void LoadList()
{
    // Get the table from the data set
    DataTable dtable = _DataSet.Tables["Titles"];

    // Clear the ListView control
    listView1.Items.Clear();

    // Display items in the ListView control
    for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow drow = dtable.Rows[i];

        // Only row that have not been deleted
        if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
        {
            // Define the list items
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["title"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["title_id"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["price"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["pubdate"].ToString());

            // Add the list items to the ListView
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
}
```

Find sorting etc also at - 
http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_listview_sort_dataset.html

Modified -

```
// Clear the ListView control
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            int ColCount = dtable.Columns.Count;
            //Add columns
            for (int k = 0; k < ColCount; k++)
            {
               listView1.Columns.Add(dtable.Columns[k].ColumnName);
            }
            // Display items in the ListView control
            for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow drow = dtable.Rows[i];

                // Only row that have not been deleted
                if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                {
                    // Define the list items
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow[0].ToString());
                    for (int j = 1; j < ColCount; j++)
                    {
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(drow[j].ToString());                        
                    }
                    // Add the list items to the ListView
                    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) -- an open source wrapper around a .NET WinForms ListView -- has a `DataListView` subclass which does exactly this.

You can give it a data source (which can be a `DataView`,
`DataTable`,
`DataSet`,
`DataViewManager`, or
`BindingSource`), and it will auto create columns and fill in the rows, to make fully functional list view. You just need one line of code:

```
this.dataListView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables["Persons"];
```